# Free C++ open source compression libraries with support for zip and zip64?

Tags: c++, compression, archive

I'm looking for a library that supports zip and zip64 formats, I was looking at zlib but that doesn't appear to have support for zip or zip64 formats...

The license should preferably be allowed to be used in closed source applications.

Comment: You may want to check out the zlib/contrib/minizip folder in the zlib distribution, it allows you to do some basic creation/manipulation of .zip files.  Dunno if it supports zip64 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) libraries. The [zip sublibrary](http://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html) in particular. It is licensed under the Boost software license, which allows using code in closed source projects.

Comment: Excuse me, can you help me answer some questions about Poco::Zip library?